# Player for recording and listening to internet radio - alternative to Screamer Radio

Tags: windows, gratis, streaming, radio

I want to find alternative to [Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/), that was not in active development since 2010.

[Key requirements](http://www.screamer-radio.com/features/):

- freeware, preferable open source
- support of all popular radio stream formats
- built-in and updateable catalog of popular radio stations
- playing stream from given URL
- managing list of manually-added streams and favourite streams
- advanced recording: ability to record whole current song, even if record button was pressed after several minutes of playing

Ideally, app should be dedicated to playing internet radio, and not be some huge, multi-feature music player. It don't need to be able to play local files, at all.